# Login without breaking the user flow

Tags: website-design, workflow, user-expectation

Let's say a user wants to perform an action that requires him to be logged in (e.g. [sending a private message](http://www.example.com/send-private-message)) so a link is provided to him to log in with a message similar to the following:

> Only registered users can perform this action. If you have an account,
>   [log in](http://www.example.com/log-in).

Should the user be redirected back to the [send private message screen](http://www.example.com/send-private-message) after the authentication process (log in)?

In other words:

1. Send private message screen (user unauthenticated)
2. Log in
3. Send private message screen (user authenticated)

Is this the most user-accessible way to keep the user doing what he originally intended to, without breaking his flow?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try shopping anything on amazon without logging in first.

> Browse -> pickout the item -> add to card -> proceed to check-out -> log-in -> continue with address selection and payment.

Amazon can easily be the top player who needs to worry about user flow and logging in :) So, **YES, login should just be a step outside the flow and back in** i.e.

> find person -> click message -> login -> type message and send.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I was expecting to hear different opinion because this requires more work to implement :P
Good example with Amazon btw. If someone has to get user flow right it is them

Comment: @JohnDoe Hah! Should've mentioned that in the question. 'Why not to do this ...' ;)

Comment: Two strategies seem to converge in the Amazon example: Having the user commit to (and complete) the action before requiring more info (i.e. login info); and only requiring info when it is needed (i.e. just-in-time). So the login would be find person > click message > type message > login > send.

Answer (score 5):

This isn't always an option, but you could provide the log in as a **panel or overlay** without ever experientially leaving the page.